# C# : Async method with 'lock' instruction

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, locking

This question is about thread safety and asynchronous programming. I'd like to know if my eventual solution is all right.

I have a thread-safe class that looks like this :

```
public class SafeLogger
{
    public static SafeLogger Instance = new SafeLogger();

    private object lock;
    private UnsafeLogger logger;

   private SafeLogger() 
   { 
       logger = new UnsafeLogger();
   }

   public void Log(string s)
   {
       lock (lock)
       {
          logger.Log(s);
       }
   }  

}
```

If I add an async method to my class :

```
   public async void LogAsync(string s)
   {
       await Task.Run(() => Log(s));
   }
```

Is my code correct?

Comment: Code review questions are more on-topic on Code Review SE. It seems like a code review is basically what you are asking for, is that correct?

Comment: ["What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/). It is impossible to confirm your claim that your class is thread-safe, without more context. What is it that _you_ mean by "thread-safe"? What specific criteria are you trying to meet? Beyond that, there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the code you posted (other than the `async void` method), but there's also not very much code there. Not even enough to know why you bother with an `await` in a method that does nothing else.

Comment: See also [So What Is This “Thread Safe” Thing Anyway?](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/02/26/so-what-is-this-thread-safe-thing-anyway/)

Comment: The variable 'lock' is always null. You need 'private object lock = new Object();'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by threadsafe you mean only one thread will be able to execute

```
logger.Log(s);
```

at any one time, then yes this is threadsafe.

The lock statement ensures this regardless of whether the Log method is called aynchronously or not.

Comment: However as mentioned above by sevzas you will need to instantiate your lock object.